# Adding SHA-1 Key to Firebase Project After CLI Database Connection

Tags: flutter, firebase

I recently connected my Flutter project to Firebase using the CLI, but SHA-1 key wasn't prompted during the process. I understand that the SHA-1 key is necessary for certain Firebase features like Authentication. How can I manually add the SHA-1 key to my Firebase project after connecting the database via CLI? I couldn't find an option to add it during the initial setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your firebase project in firebase console(chrome), on top left you will see a settings icon click on that, go to project setting, scroll down to end you will see an "add fingerprint" button click on that paste your SHA Key it will automatically detect your key either it 256 or SHA 1 key. hopefully answer the question if you have any query comment on my answer i'll help you out